# Number of grids for different devices

Tags: android, gridview, view

I have a problem where i should know the number of `gridview`in each row which gets displayed for different devices. like number of `gridview` per row for tablets, WVGA phones ..since their screen widths are different ..is there a code to check this?

Comment: you can make constant no of rows .. so can you post your gridview xml code ?

Comment: I think its not number of gidviews but a single gridview with flexible number of columns you are talking about..For that you have to take a density independent fixed width of each column..and according to your device width you will get your number of columns

Comment: below is my gridview code...i use autofit for the numofcolumns for gridview for fitting for differnt devices 
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/gridview" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:verticalSpacing="4dp" android:horizontalSpacing="4dp" android:numColumns="auto_fit" android:columnWidth="90dp" android:stretchMode="columnWidth" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:background="#ffffff"
                    android:textFilterEnabled="true"/>

Comment: android:numColumns="auto_fit" instead of auto fit set no of columns which you want .. so fix it in device itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Okk you can set number of columns programatically using

```
float scalefactor = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 100;
int width = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
int columns = (int) ((float)width / (float) scalefactor);
gridView.setNumColumns(columns);
```

where 100 is the fixed width of each column for all devices m taking...i get 8 columns in tablet,3 in samsung 2.2 devices and 4 in samsung note

Comment: what does getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density give for explanation?

Comment: it gives dendity..for Low dpi its 0.75 and for Medium dpi its 1 and fro high dpi its 1.5...dpi(density per inch) which defines how the pixels display ur pics

Comment: getWidth() is deprecated. Instead you can do something like this 

        Point size = new Point();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);
        int number = size.x;

Comment: Can someone please explain what is logic behind:                                      `int columns = (int) ((float) number / (float) scalefactor);` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this method, [getNumColumns();](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#getNumColumns%28%29)

This will provide you with the column count.

Usage:

```
gridView.getNumColumns();
```

Comment: just a small addition.. it will return the number of columns in the grid. Returns AUTO_FIT if the Grid has never been laid out.

Comment: @AndroSelva: Thanks  for the answer..but that requires an api 11 in the manifest but i need it ti support from 8