# Generate No of Columns in grid view according to the device screen size in android

Tags: android, gridview

I am having a Gridview in my layout file, I have set these attributes to the GridView :

android:numColumns="auto_fit"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"

I want to generate no of columns according to the screen size of device. For Ex: If I am working with a Tablet the content should be shown in 2 or 3 columns and if working with small devices the content should be shown in single column, so the generation of these columns should be according to the device' size. How can I achieve this, please help me here.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link
[Number of grids for different devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133693/number-of-grids-for-different-devices)

Copied

```
 float scalefactor = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 100;
    int number = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
    int columns = (int) ((float) number / (float) scalefactor);
    gridView.setNumColumns(columns);
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for this help. I am having one more query. I am having an activity which is having a layout like it shows an image, some textviews and some other fields.
Then I am having a viewpager with 3 tabs in the same activity and having 3 fragments for these 3 tabs, I want that when I click on any of the tabs, the upper content like images, textviews should be hidden and tabs move to the upper part of the page and when I scroll it up the upper content get visible again. Can you please help me here, how can I implement it.

Thank you so much for all your help.